# SharePoint Online Branding Missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, branding

One of our employee's is currently missing the main brand stamping on our SharePoint site. Here is a screenshot of the users top SharePoint bar vs. the company's.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the second image has our company logo and is branded a specific color. The first image is missing this content. We have tried having our users clear their browser history/cache and sign-off of all of their office apps to see if the issue would resolve itself.

Has anyone encountered this issue? And if so, how is it resolved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The user appears to have set their Microsoft 365 theme to "High Contrast".

The user can change this back to your company theme by going to Delve > clicking the cog > and choosing their company theme under "Themes".